# I love the Pose Library - but once you apply pose at keyframe how do you see the pose name in action or dope sheet?

Tags: animation, armature, pose-mode

I have got my head around Pose Library. You have to be very careful to ensure the pose's you store are only associated with the bones you want to change. But once working pretty awesome!

Thing is once you keyframe a pose and switch to Dope Sheet or Action Editor it reverts to just showing you the transforms on each bone. I am guessing this is because the pose library is a bit of a hack which just transforms armature at keyframe then forgets about it.

Now perfect scenario for me would be to have a dope sheet view with keyframe timeline for armature  tagged with the pose lib/pose name. Any addons that can do that or a hidden feature of Blender I have not found? If not any way to tag or comment parts of animation in dope sheet to remember what the hell doing?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure it will help but you can create markers in the Dope Sheet: M to create, G to move, ctrl M to name, X to delete. You can create shortcuts to jump to next or previous marker. But if you move a series of keyframes the markers won't follow.

Comment: Thanks moonboots that is very useful. Good to know they don't move with key frames but I can work with this.